# Android-like R.java for non-Android project?

Tags: java, android

Over the years of developing for Android, I find my self very accustomed to its R.java centered resource design. Is it possible to make a similar class or design to mimic how resources are aquired through R.java? (Ex: getString(R.string.text))

This question may be confusing; let me know what I need to elaborate about.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't just create an R.java file yourself?

Comment: @gobernador, Well the file generates automatically and updates when a file is added to the res folder. Making it myself kind of defeats the purpose. I tried to, and it just isn't efficient enough.

Comment: You're going to need something external, in your build script or something. There's nothing I'm aware of that's built into vanilla Java. However, if you do develop something, post it here, because there are others, including me, who would love to use that also.